# Saving data in local storage using a GET request when installing an Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a google-chrome extension that requires downloading data in JSON format from a file that I already put on my Github account. This data should be installed once, when installing the extension or after it is opened first. However I am unable to do so.

I tried using **window.onInstalled**, however this is not working. Here is a snippet from the file popup.js:

```
for(let i=0;i<tags.length;i++){
         chrome.storage.local.get(tags[i],function(data){
           console.log(data);
           if (typeof data[tags[i]] == 'undefined'){
              alert(tags[i] + " Data Not Found");
              if(navigator.onLine){
                  alert("Downloading Data from External Source... May take a while");
                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: urls[i],
                      data: { get_param: 'value'},
                      dataType: 'json',
                      complete: function(data){
                          alert("Download Complete");
                          htmljson = data.responseJSON;
                          var len = Object.keys(htmljson).length;
                          let key = tags[i];
                          chrome.storage.local.set({key:htmljson},function(){
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  }
              else{
                alert("Connection Could not Established. Check your Internet Connection!");
              }
           }
           else{
            console.log("Data Not Found");
           }
          });
}
```

Tags is just an array that has the key value that I want to map the data to in local storage. 
This code also sometimes results in downloading the data multiple times before it starts working fine.
I did try finding solution on internet, however could not find anything useful. Any help or suggestion is fine regarding how could I achieve this. 
If my method is wrong, could you please suggest how should I work around it?

Comment: There's no such event as `window.onInstalled`. There is chrome.runtime.onInstalled for which you can find examples in the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:oninstalled) and documentation, but it must be used in the background script, not in the popup script.

Comment: okay, thanks for correction. But is there a way I can do it from here, I mean from popup.js

Comment: You can check `localStorage.installed` and if it's not present then it's the first run. In that case you'll set localStorage.installed to true and fetch the data. You can use chrome.storage.local instead of localStorage, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot / should not do it from the `popup.js`.
instead, do it from the background page, using the [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onInstalled) API.
Then you can have your `popup.js` look at the data as you have today.